# PHP regular. Convert deg, min, sec => lat, lng

Tags: php, google-maps, coordinates

I have a string containing deg, mins, secs. It could contain 4-6 numbers, letter, 4-6 numbers, letter.

For example: 5128N00028W, 5057N00121W, 505551N0012215W

**Question:** What is the fastest way to convert this string to lat, lng to use it in Google Maps?

Comment: Do you have a general idea of where these coordinates are supposed to be? Somewhere in the UK, perhaps?

Comment: @duskwuff they could be all over the world

Comment: I mean specifically for the examples you gave.